# aws toolkit breaks visual studio 2013 after install

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2013

I installed visual studio 2013 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine and then installed the AWS toolkit (AWSToolsAndSDKForNet_sdk-2.3.39.0-ps-2.3.39.0-tk-1.9.3.1.msi) directly after. After installing the toolkit, the activity log contains the following errors when I attempt to start visual studio. No other changes were made to the installation. Any ideas?

```
24 ERROR No InprocServer32 registered for package [MRU Package]
          %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll {8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3} 8007007e VisualStudio 2015/05/26 23:32:43.228 

36 ERROR No InprocServer32 registered for package [MRU Package]
          %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll {8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3} 8007007e VisualStudio 2015/05/26 23:32:50.026 

60 ERROR No InprocServer32 registered for package [Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage]
          %windir%\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL {CF6A5C16-83B0-4D04-B702-195C35C6E887} 8007007e VisualStudio 2015/05/26 23:33:17.761 

61 ERROR Construction of frame content failed. Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{3ae79031-e1bc-11d0-8f78-00a0c9110057} Frame caption: Solution Explorer Exception details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid& packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid& context) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()   VisualStudio 2015/05/26 23:34:02.415 

69 ERROR No InprocServer32 registered for package [MRU Package]
          %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll {8FF5C2A8-5EBA-4717-8EE1-46B6427D8FF3} 8007007e VisualStudio 2015/05/26 23:34:03.169 

75 ERROR No InprocServer32 registered for package [Global Search Package]
          %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll {18333854-D2FF-44A3-98D8-40501B914D7D} 8007007e VisualStudio 2015/05/26 23:34:04.093 

77 ERROR No InprocServer32 registered for package [Global Search Package]
          %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll {18333854-D2FF-44A3-98D8-40501B914D7D} 8007007e VisualStudio 2015/05/26 23:34:04.969 

79 ERROR No InprocServer32 registered for package [Global Search Package]
          %windir%\system32\mscoree.dll {18333854-D2FF-44A3-98D8-40501B914D7D} 8007007e VisualStudio 2015/05/26 23:34:11.362
```

Comment: I had the same issue after installing vs 2015

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32180152/aws-toolkit-breaks-vs-2015 for a similar issue.