# AWS toolkit Breaks VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015

I installed visual studio 2015 on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. I already had vs 2013 and vs 2012 installed. After installing vs 2015, I was no longer able to open vs 2012/2013 and received the following prompt: "A problem occurred when loading the Microsoft Visual Menu.... [(similar issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506703/problems-occurred-when-loading-the-microsoft-visual-menu)" However vs 2015 was able to open and was working properly.

I then installed AWS toolkit (AWSToolsAndSDKForNet_sdk-3.1.5.0_ps-3.1.5.1_tk-1.9.6.3.msi). After installing the toolkit, I was no longer able to open vs 2015. I uninstalled AWS toolkit and still can't open vs 2015 ([similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30470995/aws-toolkit-breaks-visual-studio-2013-after-install)). I then tried to uninstall vs 2015 and I kept receiving an error just to open the change program option. No other changes were made to the installation.

Another thing, I noticed is that a lot of my programs the icons are broken and don't appear. I just see the standard exe icon that comes with windows.

**Any ideas?**